# Adding a diacritic mark to string fail in c++

Tags: c++, string, diacritics

I want to add a diacritic mark to my `string` in `c++`. Assume I want to modify `wordz` string in a following manner:

```
String respj = resp[j];                     
std::string respjz1 = respj;   // create respjz1 and respjz2 
std::string respjz2 = respj;

respjz1[i] = 'ź';   // put diacritic marks
respjz2[i] = 'ż';
```

I keep receiving: `wordş` and `wordĽ` (instead of `wordź` and `wordż`). I tried to google it but I keep getting results related to the opposite problem - diacritic normalization to non-diacritic mark.

Comment: Have you tried using unicode?

Comment: What compiler is this?

Comment: Check about encoding of the compiler?

Comment: Well, in fact I use `c++` functions via the `Rcpp` plugin in `R`(`R` is an environment for statistical computations) and thought there might be a `c++` function to force the proper encoding. If not, I suppose it might be a deeper problem as the functon is compiled in `R` itself.

Comment: You have to identify the environmental encoding first. Then, you can introduce the character you want using the code for that. Bear in mind, the encoding for those characters could be multibyte. For example, 'ź' character could be written in utf-8 as `"\xe0\x85\xba"` (Unicode character U+017A encoded as utf-8).

Comment: @Gonmator U+17A would be 0xC5, 0xBA in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what is `String`?  Does it support accented characters or not?

But the real issue is one of encodings.  When you say "I keep
receiving", what do you mean.  What the string will contain is
not a character, but a numeric value, representing a code point
of a character, in some encoding.  If the encoding used by the
compiler for accented characters is the same as the encoding
used by whatever you use to visualize them, then you will get
the same character.  If it isn't, you will get something
different.  Thus, for example, depending on the encoding, LATIN
SMALL LETTER Z WITH DOT (what I think you're trying to assign to
`respjz2[i]`) can be 0xFD or 0xBF in the encoding tables I have
access to (and it's absent in most single byte encodings); in
the single byte encoding I normally use (ISO 8859-1), these code
points correspond to LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH ACUTE and
INVERTED QUESTION MARK, respectively.

In the end, there is no real solution.  Long term, I think you
should probably move to UTF-8, and try to ensure that all of the
tools you use (and all of the tools used by your users)
understand that.  Short term, it may not be that simple: for
starters, you're more or less stuck with what your compiler
provides (unless you enter the characters in the form `\u00BF`
or `\u00FD`, and even then the compiler may do some funny
mappings when it puts them into a string literal).  And you may
not even know what other tools your users use.

Comment: James Kanze, I truly appreciate your answer. I have quite small set of characters I am going to use, so I will try to perform some basic mapping. Thank you!